# Javascript/Firebase - Why does function return undefined instead of true or false?

Tags: javascript, firebase, function, firebase-realtime-database, return-value

I'm use this function to check Answer. Value of `compareAns` should return true/false but it return undefined.

[Return undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrlxT.png)

[Data in firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7brFa.png)

```
function compareAns(quiz, ansIndex) {
    let ansRef = firebase
        .database()
        .ref("Questions/" + quiz + "/ans/" + ansIndex);
    ansRef.on("value", (snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            return snapshot.val().is_correct;
        } else console.log("No data");
    });
}
```

Comment: Because you are not returning anything from the function. The only `return` in that snippet is inside of a call back. And even that callback does not always return a value ... But that has nothing to do with the return value for the function itself.

Comment: This is probably very similar to returning a response from a promise/async request, since you are literally awaiting on the `value` event. You'd probably want `compareAns` to return a promise, that resolves with the value from `snapshot`